# dhtmlx scheduler scheduler.getState().date reacting differently in Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: jquery, scheduler, dhtmlx

I am trying to access the current date of the calendar to invoke a piece of code to adjust the first_hour and last_hour on the calendar. Here is the code.

```
$(".dhx_cal_today_button, .dhx_cal_prev_button, .dhx_cal_next_button")
                .click(
                        function() {
var formatFunc = scheduler.date.date_to_str("%D");
                            var dayTarget = formatFunc(scheduler.getState().date).toUpperCase();

                            scheduler.config.first_hour = dayScheduleAM[dayTarget];
                            scheduler.config.last_hour = daySchedulePM[dayTarget];
                            scheduler.config.mark_now = true;
                            scheduler.setCurrentView();
                            scheduler.updateView();

                        });
```

Now comes the weird part. When I run this in firefox, the scheduler has actually moved to the next or previous day while in Chrome it still shows the last day. For example, if I am on Monday and I click next, firefox debug shows scheduler.getState().date as Tuesday but chrome shows Monday still.

Any idea what is happening? Also, is there another way to wait for dhtmlx js to finish its processing before the .click is invoked? I do not want to write +1/-1 day logic as that would run into problem with firefox and who knows with what other future versions of browsers.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to have my above function execute after dhtmlxscheduler.js bound functions. Any idea on how I can do that? In firefox the dhtmlx functions are executed first and then my function while in Chrome it is the other way around.

Comment: If anybody has an elegant solution then do provide one. At the moment I am determining whether the browser is Chrome or not and then adjusting the date manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue can be caused by the order of events processing ( what goes first, the scheduler's or custom event handlers )

Instead of attaching the handler, you can attach a handler to the onBeforeViewChange event

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeViewChange", function(m,d, nm, nd){
  if (d*1 != nd*1{
       //active date was changed, place the custom logic here
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Aquatic. I have updated your answer as d*1 != nd*1 is always true at the millisecond. In my code, I used momentjs and formatted that to YYYY-MM-DD before comparing and that helped get the actual values otherwise even on page refresh or reload of events due to change in one event was triggering the logic unnecessarily.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Still in above case the d and nd object will differ only if date was changed.It can re result of pressing on prev, next or today button. If some other button was pressed, the d and nd will point to the same Date object

Comment: I submitted edits which were declined. So, here is the code that works. The above answer will always give true and there is a missing ) in the if condition.

Comment: var prevDate = moment(d*1);
 var newDate = moment(nd*1);
 // d*1 and nd*1 always differ on the millisecond so comparing them will always for not equals will always yield true. With respect to DHTMLX Scheduler, comparing the date without timestamp will present the right behavior.
 if (prevDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') != newDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) { 

   //active date was changed, place the custom logic here 

  }